# Find out who compressed the files

Tags: windows-7, security, user-accounts, compression, rar

I received a message that contains a compressed RAR file.

How can find out who compressed the files and created RAR file? (the user account or computer name)

Comment: Who sent the message / where did you get it?

Comment: I mean the user account or computer name!

Comment: copmressed in the title correct it

Comment: I think there is no way you could know from a `RAR` file..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RAR file format](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/RAR) does not contain such information. In fact, I'm not aware of any common archive format that automatically stores information about who created the archive, or on which computer it was created.